# Como tratar Letras caixa alta e baixa, juntamente com Símbolos

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho o seguinte *snippet* rodando bonitinho:

```js
function busca() {
  var str = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  
  if(document.getElementById(str))
    console.log(str + ' existe.');
  else
    console.log(str + ' ñ existe');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt"><input type="button" value="mais" onclick="busca()">

<pre>Ex.: vaca, boi, porco ou galinha</pre>

<div id='vaca'></div>
<div id='boi'></div>
<div id='porco'></div>
<div id='galinha'></div>
```

Agora pretendo tratar alguns detalhes a mais ...

Suponhamos que, no documento HTML ha outros `id` segmentado assim:

`id='vaca-leiteira'`

`id='boi-nelore'`

`id='Porco_granja'`

`id='gaLinha_caIpirA'`

Note que temos sua designação seguido de um *hífen* ou *underline*, e tendo algumas variações entre "vogais" e "consoantes" sendo *maiúsculas* e/ou *minúsculas*.

Como posso resolver isso quando for digitar no campo de texto? Tipo:

- vaca Leiteira
- galinha caipira

Veja que não faço o uso de *hífen* e/ou *underline*, e ainda coloco alguma vogal ou consoante em *maiúsculas* e/ou *minúsculas* fora do escopo da identificação, tudo de propósito. Mesmo assim quero o resultado certeiro.

> Em tudo a charada é, **ignorar** estes pontos e trazer o resultado final. Teria que fazer uso de alguma `RegExp`?

Comment: Peraí, você quer tratar letras e símbolos aleatórios ? {@#$#@%#@%@#&} ?

Comment: Ah sim, entendi a pergunta agora, realmente precisa de tratamento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diego, segue uma **alternativa** de solução que elaborei aqui rapidamente, basicamente o que faço é pegar todos os `ids` dos elementos, depois retiro todos os caracteres especiais com `.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ' ')` e os deixo em caixa baixa com `.toLowerCase()`, depois simplesmente verifico se o valor do `input` consta na lista de ids formatados, enfim o código ta bem auto-explicativo.

```js
function busca() {
  var str = document.getElementById('txt').value;

  var ids = pegaTodosIds();
  var idsFormatados = FormataIds(ids);

  //if (idsFormatados.includes(str.toLowerCase()))
  if (idsFormatados.indexOf(str.toLowerCase()) > -1)
    console.log(str + ' existe.');
  else
    console.log(str + ' ñ existe');
}


function pegaTodosIds() {
  var todosElementos = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  var todosIds = [];
  for (var i = 0, n = todosElementos.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var elemento = todosElementos[i];
    if (elemento.id) {
      todosIds.push(elemento.id);
    }
  }
  return todosIds;
}

function FormataIds(ids) {
  var idsFormatados = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    //console.log(ids[i]);
    var nova_str = ids[i].replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ' ').replace('_', ' ').toLowerCase();
    idsFormatados.push(nova_str);
  }
  return idsFormatados
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt"><input type="button" value="mais" onclick="busca()">

<pre>Ex.: vaca, boi, porco ou galinha</pre>

<div id='vaca' class=''></div>
<div id='boi'></div>
<div id='porco'></div>
<div id='galinha'></div>
<div id='vaca-leiTeira'></div>
<div id='cavaLo_crioulo'></div>
<div id='porco-aranha'></div>
<div id='gaLinha_caIpirA'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso da forma mais performática possível, sugiro usar um mapa/dicionário. Em Javascript, todo objeto é um dicionário, então você já tem meio caminho andado.

Coloque todos os seus elementos em um dicionário. Sugiro dar uma uma classe comum aos elementos nos quais realizará a busca. Por exemplo, "agro". I.e.:

```
<div id="pato" class="agro"></div>
<div id="urtiga" class="agro"></div>
```

Assim você obtém todos os elementos da seguinte forma:

```
var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("agro");
```

O método getElementsByClassName retorna um vetor. Agora você converte o vetor para um mapa, já normalizadas as chaves para um padrão todo minúsculo e sem caracteres que não sejam letras não-acentuadas. O valor de cada chave pode ser qualquer coisa, desde que seja logicamente diferente de falso.

```
var mapa = {};
for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    string id = elementos[i].id;
    id = id.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
    id = id.toLowerCase();

    mapa[id] = true;
}
```

Agora, para saber se existe algum elemento correspondente a um texto informado, é fácil:

```
var texto = document.getElementById('txt').value;
var input = texto.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "").toLowerCase();
var existe = !!mapa[input];

console.log(texto + (existe ? " existe" : " não existe"));
```

Comment: Estou  tentando a um bom tempo envolver esta tua solução dentro da `function busca() { // código do Renan }`, mas infelizmente o _console_ acusa - **busca is not defined**. O que estou a fazer de errado?

Comment: Para saber precisamos ver o código. Sugiro usar o jsfiddle.net. A mensagem de erro indica que a função busca não existe no escopo onde é chamada, que pode ser distinto do escopo onde foi declarada.

Answer (score 0):

Sou grato a [Renan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1658/renan) e [Mathias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/67721/mathias) que me deram suas resposta, onde pude chegar ao resultado final:

```js
function busca() {

var elemento = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    var texto = document.getElementById('txt').value;

    var campo = texto.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, " ").toLowerCase();

var mapa = [];

    for (var i in elemento) {
        var identifica = elemento[i].id;
    var resultado = identifica.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, " ").toLowerCase();

        mapa.push(resultado);
    }

if (mapa.indexOf(campo) > -1)
 
  console.log("Sim temos " + texto);
       else 
  console.log("Não temos " + texto);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt"><input type="button" value="mais" onclick="busca()">

<pre>
Exemplos: vaca, boi, porco ou galinha

 - ou -

vaca Leiteira, boi nelore, Porco granja, gaLinha caIpirA'
</pre>

<div id='vaca' class=''></div>
<div id='boi'></div>
<div id='porco'></div>
<div id='galinha'></div>
<div id='vaca-leiteira'></div>
<div id='boi-nelore'></div>
<div id='Porco_granja'></div>
<div id='gaLinha_caIpirA'></div>
```

## Explicação

O *método* `replace` com expressão regular `/[^a-zA-Z]/g`, remove os símbolos *hífen*/*underline*

E aliado com `toLowerCase()`, que deixa as palavras *maiúsculas* em *minúsculas*

Agora podemos verificar com `if` se coincide.